# Dynamic content in outlook email messages

Tags: html, dynamic, outlook, message

I need to have a button in my outlook message that displays an image (inside the message itself) when clicked. I tried to put a HTML with Javascript handling onclick event, but scripts wont work inside outlook emails. What can I do to get it done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not run in emails, it would be a security risk (and an annoyance). You are actually very restricted on most clients, when I was styling a newsletter for a client I had to resort to table layouts.

The best you can do is put a link in the email which will redirect the user to a web page.